# Is motor current proportional to thrust?

Tags: quadcopter, brushless-motor

So I was making sure my circuit for an airboat I was working on was safe. And checking a motor, it has 35 amps max current running 11.1v at 1000. (However my ESC has a 30 current, 40 burst amps).

The recommended tested prop for this is a 11x9 3-blade and runs the motor at 20 amps. Doing some quick calculations via on online calculator, it appears to give a value of 5.4lbs of force (way off to the 2.65 lbs measured, but regardless...). When I type in a prop I want (13x6) it gives a thrust value of 7.53 .

Now, if the motor current is proportional to the thrust, 5.4 lbs / 20 amps = 7.53 / running amps. And therefore the amount of amps the prop would be, in theory a little less than 30 if this is indeed the case. Thus safe for my application.

This would also make sense in physics terms as Power = Current*Voltage which is proportional to thrust, but just need to make sure.

So does this thought process work for choosing a prop? My device will  be doing very short runs (less than 25 seconds), so near-boundaries should be safe...

Comment: What motor are you using? can you clarify what you're saying and asking?  are you saying the motor has a max load of 35A while running on a 3S battery (11.1v) at 1000 RPM? what calculations did you do to get 5.4LB of force?